# Sort files by date added not modified

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, bash-scripting

I am trying to open the last application that was added to the `/Applications` directory on MacOS.

For now, in order to find the latest app and open it, I run:

```bsh
open -a "$(ls -t1 /Applications/ | head -1)"
```

However, the command provides the last app that was **modified**, and not the last app that was **added** to the `/Applications` directory.

Sometimes an app content will change and then will get before an app that was just added to the directory.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateAdded is Apple's file metadata, so use `mdls` to produce the filename and it's dateadded attribute.

```
mdls -n kMDItemFSName -n kMDItemDateAdded /Applications/*.app
```

Now use `cut`,`paste`,`sort` and `head` to modify the output

```
mdls -n kMDItemFSName -n kMDItemDateAdded /Applications/*.app |
        cut -d= -f 2- | paste -d' ' - - | sort -rn | head -n1 | cut -d\" -f 2
```

EDIT:
This is a bit more streamlined.

```
mdls -n kMDItemFSName -n kMDItemDateAdded -raw /Applications/*.app | xargs -0 -n2 | sort -rn | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f4-
```